Quantum Espresso error in Wainner90
When I run my input file (open_grid.x) in Quantum ESPRESSO, I face this error. How can I solve this error?
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f250ca67d11 in ???
#1  0x7f250ca66ee5 in ???
#2  0x7f250c70b08f in ???
    at /build/glibc-LcI20x/glibc-2.31/signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sigaction.c:0
#3  0x55aed4d4683d in ???
#4  0x55aed4cf7d2f in ???
#5  0x55aed4cd5510 in ???
#6  0x55aed4cd4eee in ???
#7  0x7f250c6ec082 in __libc_start_main
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#8  0x55aed4cd4f2d in ???
#9  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
Segmentation fault (core dumped) 


Platform and QE version? Are you running QE on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) or some virtual machines?

I am using QE in ubuntu 20.04.6 lts. QE version is 7.0, I'm running HSE06 calculation for 2D material MoS2 to calculate band structure, if I run (open_grid.x) i face the error so tell me what can i do ?

How many atoms are you simulating? Is it possible that you're running out of RAM? How much RAM does your computer have?

its 8gb ram, and the atoms is 3 its MoS2 unit cell.
